# Installing MonoDevelop on Windows: workaround for Gtk# requirement?

Tags: windows, mono, installation, monodevelop, gtk#

I have already installed *Mono* (version 2.11.4) on my Windows 7 system, and now I intend to install *MonoDevelop* (version 3.0.4.7). However, when I start the *MonoDevelop* installer I get the following error message, and the installation is terminated:

[image: MonoDevelop installation error]

OK, this can be easily fixed by obtaining the *Gtk#* installer from [here](http://download.mono-project.com/gtk-sharp/gtk-sharp-2.12.10.win32.msi). However, the *Mono* installation already includes *Gtk# 2.12.11*, so it really seems like an unnecessary step to also install *Gtk#* separately.

When *Mono* including *Gtk#* is already installed, is there **any** way to instruct the *MonoDevelop* installer to (additionally) look for the required *Gtk#* files in the *Mono* installation directories?

**UPDATE** I have tried to install "dummy" registry settings for *Gtk#*, specifying the *Mono* root directory as the *Gtk#* installation folder. This allows me to install *MonoDevelop* without having to install *Gtk#* separately, but I am not able to **run** *MonoDevelop* afterwards...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install GTK# for .NET, because the GTK# included with Mono is in Mono's GAC, not .NET's GAC, and the MonoDevelop installer is specifically designed to install MonoDevelop such that it runs on the .NET runtime. Although it *should* be possible to run MD on Mono on Windows, running on .NET is all that's tested and officially supported.

You can still *target* Mono while running on .NET - MonoDevelop will detect installed Mono runtimes. and they'll show up in the "target runtime" menu.

Comment: Aha. Many thanks for the clarification! Is this mentioned in somewhere in the official documentation?

Comment: It's not AFAIK, unfortunately.