# MonoDevelop not installing on Windows: Gtk# issue

Tags: windows, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

Similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025828/installing-monodevelop-on-windows-workaround-for-gtk-requirement?answertab=active#comment17710015_13035812/), although the solution for the linked thread has not worked for me.

Restating the problem: I have Mono 2.10.9 installed and going on my Windows 8, but cannot install MonoDevelop (I'm actually trying MD version 3.0.6 found on sourceforge, it seems that the latest release has no Windows support yet). When running the msi installer, I get the

> Gtk# version 2.12.9 or greater must be installed.

error message even after installing Gtk# 2.12.20 for .NET (as found on MD Windows download session).

I even tried editing MD msi file (as recommended [here](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Monodevelop-2-8-5-Windows-7-failed-to-install-with-Gtk-2-12-9-error-message-td4245817.html)) but that has not worked either.

Any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same problem. I actually fixed it through this from the forum you posted.

1. Download and Install [ORCA MSI Editor](https://www.technipages.com/download-orca-msi-editor).
2. Now right-click Monodevelop-xxx.msi and choose Edit with Orca.
3. Select "Launch Condition" from Tables list, on the right pane will appears 2 entries
4. Edit the Condition named: `GTKSHARPVERSION >= "2.12" OR REMOVE ~= "ALL"` into `GTKSHARPVERSION >= 2.12.9 OR REMOVE ~= "ALL"`
5. Save
6. Run installer again

It didn't work at first but then I retried it a few times and actually got it to work.

Answer (score 2):

As the message says, you need Gtk# 2.12.9 or higher, whereas you have only 2.10.

Also, I would install the complete Xamarin studio msi (windows version of MonoDevelop) if I were you, instead of meddling with source code downloaded from sourceforge which is basically intended for make style development on linux.

You will find both Xamarin studio and Gtk# 2.12.20 (the latest) here:

http://monodevelop.com/Download/

Comment: I have the correct Gtk# version (2.12), the 2.10 was mistyped :( silly mistake, I'm sorry. Xamarin was actually insalled, but isn't it meant for mobile development?

Comment: Also, [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/monodevelop.mirror/files/MonoDevelop%203.0.6/) is the downloaded MD msi file. I understand and agree that I should download from the official website, but couldn't find the latest release for Windows and previous versions don't seem to exist there either.

Comment: @victorph - Xamarin Studio is used to develop both desktop and mobile apps. I'm developing gtk# apps using it without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem, and after follow the instructions above.

But, I fixed it through this from the forum you posted.

1. Download and Install `ORCA MSI Editor`.
2. Now right-click `Monodevelop-xxx.msi` and choose Edit with Orca.
3. Select "Launch Condition" from Tables list, on the right pane will appears 2 entries
4. Edit the Condition named: `GTKSHARPVERSION >= "2.12" OR REMOVE ~= "ALL"` into `GTKSHARPVERSION >= 2.12.9 OR REMOVE ~= "ALL"`
5. Save
6. Run installer again

What I did was to Edit the Monodevelop-xxx.msi with Orca and remove from Launch Condition the line `GTKSHARPVERSION >= "2.12.19" OR REMOVE ~= "ALL"` and I was able to install Xamarin studio.

But when I run Xamarin Studio the software throw the same problem please install Gtk# must be installed.

I modify again the Xamarin Studio installer and the condition back and remove the Gtk# after that I install the Gtk back and the Xamarin Studio runs OK.